# How to call Word macros from Excel

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have two macros, one in Excel, and one in Word.  The Excel Macro calls the Word macro.  My code is as follows:

Excel:

```
Public wb1 As Workbook
Public dt1 As Document

Sub openword()
Dim wpath, epath As String      'where the word document will be opened and where the excel sheet will be saved
Dim wordapp As Object           'preparing to open word
Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook

While wb1.Sheets.Count <> 1
    wb1.Sheets(2).Delete
Wend

wpath = "C:\users\GPerry\Desktop\Projects and Work\document.docm"
Set wordapp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
'Set wordapp = CreateObject(Shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\WINWORD", vbNormalFocus)) this is one I tried to make work because while word.application seems to work, I don't *understand* it, so if anyone can help, that'd be awesome
wordapp.Visible = True
Set dt1 = wordapp.Documents.Open(wpath)
wordapp.Run "divider", wb1, dt1
dt1.Close
wordapp.Quit
End Sub
```

And word:

```
Sub divider(wb1, dt1)
Set dt1 = ThisDocument
If dt1.Paragraphs.Count > 65000 Then
    Set cutrange = dt1.Range(dt1.Paragraphs(1).Range.Start, dt1.Paragraphs(65000).Range.End)
    If wb1.Sheets(Sheets.Count).Cells(1, 1) <> "" Then
        wb1.Sheets.Add After:=Sheets.Count
    End If
Else
    Set cutrange = dt1.Content
    If wb1.Sheets(Sheets.Count).Cells(1, 1) <> "" Then
        wb1.Sheets.Add After:=Sheets.Count
    End If
End If
    cutrange.Cut Destination:=wb1.Sheets(wb1.Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Cells(1, 1)
    wb1.Sheets(Sheets.Count).Cells(1, 1).TextToColumns Destination:=wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1)
End Sub
```

My problem is that the variable wb1 isn't getting passed between them.  Even though I put wb1 in the list of variables to send to the macro, when it arrives at the document, wb1 has no value inside of it.  I would re-initialize it, but I don't know how to refer to an already existing document - only how to set it equal to one as you open it.

So either how do I pass the value through into the Word macro, or how do I re-initialize this variable?  Preferably without having to set something equal to the excel application, because every time I try that it sets it equal to Excel 2003, not 2010 (though any solutions to that are also, of course, welcome).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the Excel global objects from inside of Word without explicitly qualifying them (they simply don't exist there).  In particular, that means you can't use `Sheets`.  You should also explicitly declare the variable types of your parameters - otherwise they'll be treated as `Variant`.  This is important with reference types because in that it helps prevent run-time errors because the compiler knows that the `Set` keyword is required.

```
Sub divider(wb1 As Object, dt1 As Document)
    Set dt1 = ThisDocument
    If dt1.Paragraphs.Count > 65000 Then
        Set cutrange = dt1.Range(dt1.Paragraphs(1).Range.Start, dt1.Paragraphs(65000).Range.End)
        If wb1.Sheets(wb1.Sheets.Count).Cells(1, 1) <> "" Then
            wb1.Sheets.Add After:=wb1.Sheets.Count
        End If
    Else
        Set cutrange = dt1.Content
        If wb1.Sheets(wb1.Sheets.Count).Cells(1, 1) <> "" Then
            wb1.Sheets.Add After:=wb1.Sheets.Count
        End If
    End If
    cutrange.Cut Destination:=wb1.Sheets(wb1.Sheets(wb1.Sheets.Count)).Cells(1, 1)
    wb1.Sheets(wb1.Sheets.Count).Cells(1, 1).TextToColumns Destination:=wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1)
End Sub
```

Note - you also don't need to pass `dt1` at all.  You never use the value in the parameter and actually set it to something else.  This could be a source of errors if you're using internal calls, because `dt1` is implicitly passed `ByRef` (it gets boxed when you call it through `Application.Run`).  That means whenever you call `divider`, whatever you pass to `dt1` in the calling code will change to `ThisDocument`. You should either remove the parameter or specify that it is `ByVal`.

Comment: I am confused as to how `Set dt1 = wordapp.Documents.Open(wpath)` and `dt1 = ThisDocument` turn out to be different things - don't they point to the same thing? - but if it helps, okay (what does it mean to get "boxed"?).  And...uh, what sort of variable type would cutrange be (is that the sort of variable you mean I should explicitly declare?)?  I don't really know how word vba works, so the closest I can guess is string...Also, I thought if you turn on the excel library, then you could use things like sheets and whatnot.  Should I then just cut it and return it to the excel macro?

Comment: Sorry if this is a lot of (possibly silly) questions, but I've never attempted anything close to this complicated using vba before, never used vba in word before, so it's a bit overwhelming.

Comment: You pass the variable `dt1` from Excel to Word.  The first thing you do is set it to `ThisDocument`.  It makes no difference what it was in the calling function.

Comment: It's easier to conceptualize if the variables have different names in each function.

Comment: Aaah, okay.  I am trying to keep the variables the same so that it's easier to follow what's referring to what, but it looked like that since the wb1 line was failing, so too would dt1.  So instead of this,would you recommend then just returning cutrange and letting the Excel macro handle it, since Word cannot use sheets?  Or is there a way to grant Word the ability to handle sheets?  I also still don't totally understand what you meant about declaring parameter variable types.  Thanks!

Comment: Word *can* use worksheet objects.  It just can't call `Sheets.Count` without an object reference.  Inside Excel, that's actually a call to `Excel.Application.Sheets.Count`.  Word can't find it without the implicit `Excel.Application` because that's part of the Excel application. So you call it on the passed Workbook instead.  The code above should just work.

Comment: Oh, wow, I didn't even notice the difference.  I was pretty confused when you posted all that code and I couldn't spot a change, but...okay, that makes more sense.  And it's not complaining about .sheets anymore.  Type mismatch, sure, but I can handle that over time (I hope).  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Err, not to keep bothering, but one more question: does copying (or cutting) from word and pasting in excel have anything to be wary of?  Because what you wrote gives type mismatch, I assume from the double `wb.sheets(`, but then reducing that gives named argument not found.  Just cutting is fine, but paste told me that it does not support this object or method, and pastespecial put it down as an image (this one struck me as weirdest)?  What is making these fail?

Comment: @GrahamPerry - What line is the type mismatch on?

Comment: `cutrange.Cut Destination:=wb1.Sheets(wb1.Sheets(wb1.Sheets.Count)).Cells(1, 1)`  other than the double `wb1.sheets(`, I don't see anything odd about it, though.  And I can't imagine there's anything Excel would complain about with pasting text into a cell.

Comment: Oh, missed that.  That's a different issue - you'll need to do separate cut and paste operations.  Word.Range.Cut doesn't have a destination parameter.  That's an Excel thing.

Comment: I was confused though because I tried that, and then it gave me an "object doesn't support this property or method".  Is it because the range object in a word file is different from range in an excel file?  Can I allow it to use and then force it to use the excel version of these commands?

Comment: @GrahamPerry - Yep, they're completely different.  See [`Word.Range`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845882.aspx) and [`Excel.Range`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Borrowed from another SO link.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wdApp As Object, newDoc As Object
    Dim strFile As String

    strFile = "C:\Some\Folder\MyWordDoc.dotm"

    '~~> Establish an Word application object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    wdApp.Visible = True

    Set newDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add(strFile)

    Call wdApp.Run("YHelloThar", "Hello")

    '
    '~~> Rest of the code
    '
End Sub
```